Trying to show a function is decreasing

Show that $f(x)= \frac{x\cot (x)-1}{x^2}$ is decreasing on $(0, \pi/2)$.

It's getting complicated by taking derivative because $f'(x)= \frac{2-x^2\csc^2(x)-x\cot(x)}{x^3}$ which is getting difficult to show negative. Any quick way to show $f$ decreasing?

I note that $x \cot(x) -1$ is decreasing and $x^2$ is increasing on $I = (0,\pi/2)$.  And to show $x \cot(x) -1$ is decreasing, $\cot(x)$ is negative on $I$ and $- x \csc^2(x)$ is a minus sign in front of the product of two positive things.

The trick here is to rewrite the function. Notice that $f(x) = \frac{xcotx-1}{x^2} = \frac{cotx}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}$. From here, you should be able to solve the problem. Specifically, consider behavior of the two functions $\frac{cotx}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, and then combine them.
Notice that for the first function $\frac{cotx}{x}$, we have that $\cot(x) = \frac{cosx}{sinx}$ is decreasing on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ since $\cos(x)$ decreases on this interval while $\sin(x)$ increases on this interval, and $\frac{1}{x}$ also decreases on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.
I'll leave the rest for you to figure out, but all you need to do is to show that $\frac{1}{x^2}$ decreases at a smaller rate than $\frac{cotx}{x}$, so that when you combine the two to get $f(x) = \frac{cotx}{x} + -\frac{1}{x^2}$, you get a decreasing function on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

HLDN, could you write how it is possible to prove that $;\dfrac1{x^2};$ decreases at a smaller rate than $;\dfrac{\cot x}x;?;$
